# How to find not an exact match in an array?

Tags: php

I use the code below on a couple of sites as a basic filter of user input before I save it to a .txt file to use later.

My problem on this one is that I want it to remove the line if it contains the word in $stopwords but is not neccesarily an exact match.

I changed the $stopwords below for the purposes of this example as I din't want it to get picked up as spam.

But as an example if I would want it to remove the line from the array if
one of the stopwords was in the line.

So if a line contained bad or badgirl or notbad then I want the line to be removed.

At the moment it has to be an exact match as am using strcmp but what is the better/correct way of doing this??

```
    $stopwords = "bad|badword|bad";
$stopwords = explode('|', $stopwords);
for ($i=0; $i<count($lines); $i++)
{
    $lines[$i] = substr($lines[$i], 0, -1);
    $lines[$i] = preg_replace('/(\s)+/', ' ', $lines[$i]);
    $lines[$i] = strtolower($lines[$i]);
    foreach($stopwords as $stopword)
    {
        if (0 == strcmp($lines[$i], $stopword))
        {
            unset($lines[$i]);
            //echo 'deleted'. $lines[$i];
        }
    }
    $lines[$i] = trim($lines[$i]);
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: be careful with your `unset`. you have to break loop too, because on next step, $lines[$i] won't be defined in `if` condition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use strpos, like this:

```
if(strpos($lines[$i], $stopword) !== FALSE)
{
    unset($lines[$i]);
}
```

Make sure you use !== and not !=, since strpos can also return 0 which equals false.

Comment: Thanks that seems to work fine and is removing the lines that contain bad words.

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular expressions. They match for parts of words (or even whole words/sentences if you want).

Read about it here: [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Example:

```
// The "i" after the pattern delimiter indicates a case-insensitive search
if (preg_match("/php/i", "PHP is the web scripting language of choice.")) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have an array of lines. For matching instead of a string:

> $stopwords = "bad|badword|bad"; // convert to regex pattern

1. regex, using [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)
2. further break lines into words, in line [explode()](http://php.net/explode)
3. combine both for more accuracy (ie. bbadword vs bodword). After `explode()` and the resulting key-value array, apply regex in iteration to find closer matches which you can define ie.95% limit then it is a match, **depending on data size and algorithm used, this can run slow**